# Mean time spent in a particular region of a Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Suppose I'm visiting a city, and move between some pair of a finite number of locations every hour. The probability of me moving from location $i$ to location $j$ depends only on location $i$ so I store all of these probabilities in a transition matrix with elements $P_{ij}$. Now, some subset of locations are on the East side of the city, and the others are elsewhere. Suppose I move around the city, what is the expected length of time I spend in the East side starting from when I arrive and ending when I leave.

Comment: So you are asking about the mean exit time from a given region ("the East side"), rather than the mean time spent in it? Then the hypothesis "given you are in the East side of the city" must be made more precise: what is the distribution of your position in the East side?

Comment: I've tried to edit the question for clarity, let me know if this is still imprecise.

Comment: And now the answer most probably depends on the site (not in the East side) you start from. Assuming one knows the distribution of the first visited site in the East side starting from this site not in the East side, the problem reduces to computing the mean exit time $e(x)$ from the East side $S$ starting from each site $x$ in $S$... And *this* is well known to be the unique solution of the affine system $$e(x)=1+\sum_{y\in S}p(x,y)e(y)$$ for every $x$ in $S$. Note that the distribution of the first visited site in $S$ starting from each site not in $S$ also solves a simple linear system.

Comment: cheers, this is what I was looking for!